# How to identify what itemSelected during button click inside ListBox ItemTemplate

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone

I have an ItemTemplate that contains a simple button. When I click this button I need a way to identify the row clicked to pull out the item bound to the listbox.

XAML

```
        <ListBox Name="DemoBox" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="150">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Height="120" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Text="{Binding SomeObjProperty}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Height="120" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,-12,0,0">
                            <Button Click="ShowStuffOnMap_Click">
                                <Button.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/arrow.png"/>
                                </Button.Background>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

click handler

```
    private void ShowStuffOnMap_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //sender is the button so ...
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you have Button with a click event inside a ListBox with a SelectionChanged event? This makes up for some scary UX, if they have different actions!

The normal approach is to have a databound ListBox, and then use the SelectionChanged event to read out the selected item.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var selectedItem = listBox.SelectedItem as MyDataBoundType;

    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    // if you use the ListBox for navigation, set the SelectedIndex to -1
    // listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

But if you really really want to do it, you need to use the `Tag` property.

```
<Button Click="ShowStuffOnMap_Click" Tag="{Binding}">
```

And then in your event handler:

```
private void ShowStuffOnMap_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var selectedItem = button.Tag as MyDataBoundType;
}
```

But I still think your approach here is wrong, and stands for bad user experience, as the normal approach to a list is that the *entire* line in the list, is one-selection only.

Comment: Scary UX practice? What if for every item, there are two buttons - Share and Favorite. There are multiple cases where this can be used, and selecting an item in the list will have nothing to do with it.

Comment: The problem in question is where you have multiple functionality on a single line. It rarely calls for good UX. Things like Share and Favorite, would be ApplicationBar buttons, on a details view. Not on a list of items.

Comment: Decent example: http://www.sencha.com/files/blog/old/assets/images/20101216-eresistible-3.png - menu for specific item + rating control. Usable or not, apps have this.

Comment: It's a good example of terrible UX. Clicking on the entire restaurant listening for the menu, is a much better design, and much better user experience. And then the rating could be done in the details view, like the Windows Phone Marketplace.

Comment: http://cdn3.staztic.com/screenshots/list-it-plus-todo-list-121-1.jpg - just for comparison purposes. Users tend to be confused by "select and do" on mobile apps. Easier to click and have the action done.

Comment: Everything else on Windows Phone is select&do. It's part of the look&feel for the platform. Giving examples of how poor Android developers are at their work, isn't really justification for doing it equally bad on Windows Phone.

Comment: Sidenote: the practice I am talking about is used in Zune on Windows Phone, when you open the song list. The play button right by the song.

Comment: Agree to the original answer! Specially when developing for Windows Phone it is scary UX practice! For such cases a context menu OR ApplicationBar is the best choice as Claus already mentioned! Just look at existing apps (e.g. Outlook for Phone) which should give you a impression of good UI design; PanoramaPage--> no appbar --> context menu

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have some unique identifier in the template itself. For example, you have a `TextBlock` - give it a unique name, and when the button is pressed, search the secondary grid for the `TextBlock` with the identifier and read its `Text` property.

Comment: He's asking for the databound item, not for a UI element to change visual states on.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's bloody madness, compared to using data-bindings. You should know better.

Comment: Every situation has its better practices. With possible multiple click listeners inside a template, I will stick with a unique ID.

Comment: The better practice is to send along a binding with the a Command binding. That you should know as well. The advice for beginners however, is to use the Tag property. What you suggests is neither good practice, or smart.

Comment: Again, depends on the complexity of the UI. When you are building an a complex app, then sure - MVVM and all the fancy stuff. For something simplistic, you don't even need the Tag.

Comment: It doesn't even get more simple than using Tag. You're suggesting walking though the Visual Tree, instead of using a simple property that was invented for the purpose? Besides, you make it sound like you're on a point hunt here, providing *direct* answers, rather than *correct* answers. We're meant to do the latter.